# How to set a token that does not expire

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm making a project that have a sensor on it. (nodemcu with sensor) that passes data to my web application (django-rest using JWT auth).

Now the scenario is that the sensor is in remote area. and it's automatic that when it's on, its passing data on the api endpoint, but then I setup an authentication to my webapp using JWT. I noticed that the *access token* expires.

I want to happen is before I deploy the sensor on the remote area, I want to set it a *access token* to the device that never expires. so it can pass the data without hassle. is that possible? thanks!

Comment: I think this might help https://github.com/HealthByRo/drf-jwt-devices

Comment: wow, thanks! it will help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a GitHub reposiory offering something in the line of what you are trying to do. Has worked for me.
Walk through to instructions in https://github.com/HealthByRo/drf-jwt-devices

```
REST_FRAMEWORK={
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "jwt_devices.authentication.PermanentTokenAuthentication"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Btw, this is my current.
`REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'jwt_devices.authentication.PermanentTokenAuthentication',
    )
}
`

Do I have to replace it with only "jwt_devices.authentication.PermanentTokenAuthentication"?